# output fields on single line from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a ConvertFrom-CSV command with headers that imports a text file all good.

What I'm struggling to get my head around or what method is to display certain fields from the contents of variable.

So the contents are:-

```
ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD
11,22,33,44
55,66,77,88
99,111,222,333
```

What I want to show is say Column A & C on one line :-

```
11 33
55 77
99 222
```

Curently I get the complete dump of Column A listed then all of Column C not the two combined from the same line .

Comment: Can you include the line of code you have?

Comment: Or at least pipe your object to |get-member and paste it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output *exactly* as you describe above:

```
import-csv File.csv|`
    select-object -property @{Name="Output";Expression={$_.ColumnA + " " + $_.ColumnC;}}|`
    select-object -ExpandProperty output;
```

This:

- Imports the CSV
- Selects from the CSV a single column with a computed value of Column A concatenated with Column C, with a space between
- Selects the computed values as a simple array of strings

You can also do it without the explicit concatenation, using `[String]::Join()`:

```
import-csv File.csv|`
    select-object -property @{Name="Output";Expression={ [String]::Join(" ", @($_.ColumnA, $_.ColumnC));}}|`
    select -ExpandProperty output;
```

AFAIK, there's no advantage to using `Get-Content file.csv|convertfrom-csv` vs. `Import-CSV`, at least on cases as trivial as this.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
First get contents from file using `Get-Content` cmdlet and then pipe it to `ConvertFrom-CSV` cmdlet and finally `Select-Object` and expression syntax to combine columns.

```
Get-Content C:\Script\import.csv | ConvertFrom-CSV -Header ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,columnD | Select ColumnB,ColumnD,@{Name="ComputedAC";Expression = {$_.ColumnA + " " + $_.ColumnC }} | Export-CSV C:\script\export.csv
```

**Method 2:**
You can use select object and the expression syntax to combine columnA and ColumnC

```
Import-csv -Path C:\Script\import.csv | Select ColumnB,ColumnD,@{Name="ComputedAC";Expression = {$_.ColumnA + " " + $_.ColumnC }} | Export-CSV C:\script\export.csv
```

**Method 3** (less recommended due to performance issues):
I am creating a new `PSObject` and setting its Property and then adding that object to `$Objs` array object and then doing an `export-csv` to a new `.csv` file.  This should output into a format you want.

```
$objs =@();
$output = Import-csv -Path C:\script\import.csv | ForEach { 
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
        ColumnAC  = [String]::Concat($_.ColumnA," ",$_.ColumnC)
        ColumnB = $_.ColumnB  
        ColumnD = $_.ColumnD          
    }   
    $objs += $Object;
} 
$objs 
$objs | Export-CSv C:\script\export.csv
```

Comment: Lots of different ways doing the same thing :) Thanks both of you.